# About $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}_y^3}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-[(x-y)\cdot\omega]\omega|^2}d\omega dy$

Tags: integration, differential-calculus

An integral  has been pushed me over the edge for several weeks. It reads as:
$$\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}_y^3}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-[(x-y)\cdot\omega]\omega|^2}d\omega dy$$

I tried to calculate the surface integral inside using spherical coordinates, but it seems that I couldn't do any further calculation since the integrand function is something like
$$e^{-\big(k_1(\varphi)\sin^2\theta+k_2(\varphi)\cos^2\theta+k_3(\varphi)\sin\theta\cos\theta\big)}\sin\theta .$$
Then I tried to use variable substitution to compute,  similarly, I didn't get anything useful. I was also trying to use Maple to compute, but it didn't work at all. My original intention is to prove that the formula
$$\displaystyle e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x|^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}_y^3}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-[(x-y)\cdot\omega]\omega|^2}d\omega dy$$
is bounded.

I would be grateful if you could give me a definite result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality you can orient the axes so that the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is along the $x_3$ axis. Using also that $|\mathbf{\omega}|=1$, one has
$$|\mathbf{x}-[(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})\cdot\mathbf{\omega}]\mathbf{\omega}|^2=(\mathbf{\omega}\cdot\mathbf{y})^2-x_3^2(\omega_3^2-1).$$
Subtitution into the integral
$$I=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}_y^3}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|\mathbf{x}-[(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})\cdot\omega]\omega|^2}d\omega d\mathbf{y}$$
gives
$$I=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}_y^3}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}\exp\left[-\tfrac{1}{2}(\omega\cdot \mathbf{y})^2+\tfrac{1}{2}\left(\omega_3^2-1\right) x_3^2\right]\,d\omega d\mathbf{y}$$
$$=(2\pi)^{3/2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy_2\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy_3\int_0^\pi d\theta\,\frac{\sin\theta}{|\cos\theta|}e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}x_3^2\sin^2\theta}.$$
All three integrations are divergent.

Comment: I can't quite understand what you mean. Could you be more specific?

Comment: added some more intermediate steps; did I misinterpret your question or make a mistake?

Comment: @Carlo: I agree with Carlo, the $\mathbf y$ integral is already log-divergent in $\mathbb R_y^1$.

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker: Thank you for your patience.I just don't get the idea ‘Without loss of generality you can orient the axes so that the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is along the $x_3$ axis’.

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker: With your help, I made the following calculations: 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}_y^3}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-[(x-y)\cdot\omega]\omega|^2}d\omega dy
    \overset{\text{(1)}}{=}\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}_y^3}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-[(x-y)\cdot\omega]\omega|^2} dy d\omega\\
    =\int_{\mathbb{S}^{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\left|x\right|^{2}-\left|x \cdot \omega\right|^{2}\right)}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}_{y}^{3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left|y \cdot \omega\right|^{2}} d y\right) d \omega$$
$\int_{\mathbb{R}_{y}^{3}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left|y \cdot \omega\right|^{2}} dy$ diverges.

Comment: @ Carlo Beenakker: But there's still a problem,that is, whether (1) still holds when the integral diverges?

Comment: think of it in this way: the integrations over $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{S}^2$ are isotropic; so the answer cannot depend on how you orient the coordinate axis, so you are free to rotate it such that the $z$-axis is aligned with the vector $\mathbf{x}$.